# Writing into a cell writes in the entire range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to rename a filename and move it to another directory. In the meanwhile I am trying to store the renamed file in a range as a log.

Below is my code:

```
Sub MyRenamePDF()

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MyOldFile As String
    Dim MyNewFile As String
    Dim dt As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    dt = Format(Now(), "YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    MyFolder = "D:\test\"
    TargetFolder = "D:\output\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.pdf")

    Do While MyFile <> ""

        MyOldFile = MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
        MyNewFile = MyFolder & "\" & "0001" & "_" & dt & "_" & MyFile
        Name MyOldFile As MyNewFile

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Logs")
            Set rng = Range("B2:B100")
            For Each cell In rng
                If cell.Value = "" Then
                    cell.Value = MyNewFile
                End If
            Next cell
        End With
        FSO.MoveFile MyNewFile, TargetFolder
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

I am facing a problem in this snippet:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Logs")
    Set rng = Range("B2:B100")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Value = MyNewFile
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```

where the value `MyNewFile` gets written in the entire range instead of a specific cell i.e `B2` here.

How to do that?

Comment: Add `Exit For` after `cell.Value = MyNewFile` - though there are better ways to write to the first blank cell in a column.

Comment: That works thanks a lot. :) newbie to vba didnt know this syntax lol. Also how can i select  value a to be written in a cell in column a and value b in column b inside this loop.?

Comment: For a much cleaner way, replace everything inside the `With...End With` with `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = MyNewFile`

Comment: @anky_91 - once he does that, be sure to click the check-mark so others know there is an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `Exit For` within the `If...End IF` will exit the `For` loop once `MyNewFile` has been written to the first blank cell in Column B.

```
If cell.Value = "" Then
    cell.Value = MyNewFile
    Exit For
End If
```

But a much cleaner way to find the first blank cell in a column is with [`Range.End`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end) and `xlUp`, and `Offset`.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Logs")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = MyNewFile
End With
```